# Comment faire ressortir l'élément « reasonable or fair » de l'idiotisme « fair enough » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections, langage-informel

> **fair enough** *informal*
>  — used to say that something is reasonable or fair
>
> - “I'll wash the dishes today, and you can wash them tomorrow.” “*Fair enough*.”
> - “He needs more time.” “*Fair enough*, but we can't wait too much longer.”
>
> [ Britanica (anc. Merriam Learners), « [fair](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/fair) » ]

[*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/fair/579870) donne « très bien ! » ou « d'accord ! » ; [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair_enough#en) donne dans une ébauche « soit, admettons, d'accord » ; [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair_enough) donne « qu'à cela ne tienne, d'accord, certes, soit » et définit en trois partie : « an expression used to concede a point; denotes that, upon consideration, something is correct or reasonable; an expression of acknowledgment or understanding ».

---

Lequel préfère-t-on pour faire ressortir en interjection l'aspect « reasonable or fair », après réflexion et de manière informelle, si c'était ce qu'on voulait faire ressortir dans le premier exemple (— Je vais faire la vaisselle aujourd'hui, et tu pourras la faire demain. — [Fair enough]) ?

Comment: Le qualificatif qui me vient est *équitable*, avec pour traduction la locution: *C'est équitable*. Mais ça me semble plus soutenu que *Fair enough*.

Comment: @mouviciel N'hésite pas à le verser en réponse, avec ce bémol.

Answer (score 5):

Difficile de trouver un équivalent strict, mais je dirais *ça me parait bien* (sans point d'exclamation) pour garder l'aspect réflexion et recul.

En plus subtil, *très bien* est d'un niveau de langage juste assez formel pour introduire une pointe de distance, une idée de réflexion voire d'acceptation légèrement contrite.

En langage plus familier, on peut aussi utiliser *ça me va* dans le même sens.

> — Je vais faire la vaisselle aujourd'hui, et tu pourras la faire demain.
>
> — Ça me parait bien.

> — Très bien.

> — Ça me va.

Answer (score 2):

“I'll wash the dishes today, and you can wash them tomorrow.” “Fair enough.”

Si je voulais dire autre chose que "*fair enough*" en anglais, je dirais dans ce cas-ci "*fine by me*". Le sens qu'on veut transmettre, c'est que c'est équitable, mais du point de vue de l'interlocuteur.

On obtient donc (comme dans la réponse de guillaume31) :

*-Je vais faire la vaisselle aujourd'hui, et tu pourras la faire demain.*

-***ça me va***.

Answer (score 1):

Un régionalisme (Qc.) que j'emploierais c'est [*avoir de l'allure*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/allure#efb0db03efecd91c) (*ça a de l'allure*) pour « être vraisemblable ». Il y aussi le calque (Qc.) de l'anglais [*faire du sens*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3499) (*ça fait du sens*) pour ce qui « tient debout », lui-même possible etc. ; évidemment *to make sense* n'est pas exactement *fair enough* et ils me semblent davantage axés sur l'aspect *raisonnable* que *équitable*. Qu'à cela ne tienne !

Comment: Salut! 
A recent question & one of its answers made me aware of "prendre acte de" and its English translation: "point taken."  This exchange reminded me that "point taken" often follows "fair enough" in Eng., i.e. "Fair enough [, and]  point taken."  Although much too formal for the purposes of your question (not to mention that "point taken" seems to emphasize "acknowledgement or understanding" rather than "reasonableness/fairness), I find it interesting that these two phrases are often used together, even in informal Eng. (perhaps in order to cover all the bases/elements contained in them).

Comment: @PapaPoule [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/point/602788) en ligne backtranslates _point taken_ into _c'est juste !_, so close enough ;-) It's also useful for [_prendre acte_](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/acte/873) along the lines of the answer you refer to... it introduces _duly_ for _dont acte_, and uses _record_ for the legal meaning. Also, that question doesn't explore very much the fact that even if people generally _prennent des notes_, it doesn't mean they actually _prennent note de_, even less so _prennent acte de_ etc.

Answer (score 1):

*— Je vais faire la vaisselle aujourd'hui, et tu pourras la faire demain.

— **Ça se défend**.*

Cette expression rend bien, il me semble, le sens de ***fair enough*** qui à la fois concède à son interlocuteur le bien fondé de ce qu'il vient de dire mais, en se gardant de franchir ce pas, sous-entend quand même qu'il serait possible de le contester.